# Find parent documents with some unique child

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I have model Article

```
class Article
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories, inverse_of: nil
end
```

and I have model Category

```
class Category
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String  
end
```

I have some categories, with names like `Author`, `Security`, `Mobile` etc.
How I can find all articles with `category.name == 'Author'`?
I try this:

```
Article.where(categories: [name: 'Author'])
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why a HABTM relation must be a 1-side relation? could you tell me the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

has_and_belongs_to_many implies a n-n relation, so you really need an inverse relation if you want to query it like that.

```
class Article
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
end

class Category
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, :type => String
  has_and_belongs_to_many :articles
end
```

Now you can do this:

```
Category.where(:name => 'Author').first.articles
```

Alternatively, you could store the categories in an array in the article itself

```
class Article
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :categories, :type => Array, :default => []
end
```

Then you could do this

```
Article.in(:categories => 'Author')
```

If you really cannot change you models, try this:

```
author_category = Category.where(:name => 'Author').first
Article.in(:category_ids => author_category.id)
```

Comment: `class Article
  include Mongoid::Document
  belongs_to :category
end` Article can have many categories.

Comment: you are right, I have updated it. I really should get coffee before I write answers :-)

Comment: Example with array is good, but I want do it without array. It's impossible to select all Articles with category == 'Author' without modify models?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use following query:

```
category = Category.where(:name => 'Author').first
articles = category.articles
```

Comment: You can simply use following query:

`category = Category.where(:name => 'Author').first
articles = category.articles`
category doesn't have method articles, because I use inverse_of: nil